# configure default mount options in yocto

Tags: linux, filesystems, yocto, mount, ext4

I have a yocto meta layer which build a complete Linux distribution for an embedded system.
It is based on 'dunfell' (3.1.11) branch of yocto and using the linux mainline kernel 5.10.57.

The file system which I use is ext4 and the /etc/fstab file contains the following lines (snipped):

```
/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults              1  1
/dev/mmcblk0p4  /data ext4    defaults,x-systemd.before=network-pre        0       1
```

The *defaults* option for mounting results in the following mount configuration (`cat /proc/mounts`):

```
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p4 /data ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

I will change the default mounting option to `rw,sync,noatime,nodelalloc,barrier=1,commit=1,data=journal`.

I'm able to manipulate the /etc/fstab file manually. But how could I change the *defaults* options in my yocto recipe? I have no idea where to find the default mount options definition in the recipe.

Thanks for any Hint

**Edit:**
Clarify the question:

1. Where are the mount options defined which are used when *defaults* is configured in the fstab?
2. Where could this options configured in a yocto recipe?
3. How to change the filesystem journaling (enable/disable journal of ext4 filesystem) in the yocto recipe? I think it must be done in the WIC step when the SD Card image is created?

Answer (score 2):

`fstab` file is handled by `base-files` recipe located in:

```
poky/meta/recipes-core/base-files
```

To implement your own `fstab` file:

- **meta-custom/recipes-core/base-files/files/myfstab**
- **meta-custom/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_%.bbappend** :

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append = " file://myfstab"

do_install_append(){
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/myfstab ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know this mechanism. The question is, how could I configure the **defaults** options for the mount. I don't now where this definition is.